# Very simple task scheduler (Task based, not Timer based)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, scheduled-tasks

My app has several periodic tasks. So I created this very simple generic task scheduler (got sick of copy-pasting code, which is based on Timers). It is very very basic and simple, can you find anything wrong with it?

```
//generic scheduling-job class
public static class PeriodicTask
{
    //keep a list of scheduled actions
    static Dictionary<Action, CancellationTokenSource> _scheduledActions = new Dictionary<Action, CancellationTokenSource>();

    //schedule an action
    public static async Task Run(Action action, TimeSpan period)
    {
        if (_scheduledActions.ContainsKey(action)) return; //this action is already scheduled, get out

        var cancellationTokenSrc = new CancellationTokenSource(); //create cancellation toket so we can abort later when we want

        _scheduledActions.Add(action, cancellationTokenSrc); //save it all into our disctionary

        //main scheduling loop
        Task task = null;
        while (!cancellationTokenSrc.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (task == null || task.IsCompleted) //skip if previous invocation is still running (our requirements allow that)
                task = Task.Run(action);

            await Task.Delay(period, cancellationTokenSrc.Token);
        }
    }

    public static void Stop(Action action)
    {
        if (!_scheduledActions.ContainsKey(action)) return; //this method has not been scheduled, get out
        _scheduledActions[action].Cancel(); //stop the task
        _scheduledActions.Remove(action); //remove from the collection
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
PeriodicTask.Run(MyStaticMethod, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
PeriodicTask.Stop(MyStaticMethod);

private static void MyStaticMethod()
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Why use "static" everywhere?

Comment: @Aron why not? I want a static "fire and forget" pattern. `PeriodicTask.Run(doStuff);`

Comment: OK. I prefer to use objects so I'd be thinking `new PeriodicTask(doStuff).Run();`